# Mongoose field reset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('lodash');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var shopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {type: String, trim: true},
    description: {type: String, trim: true},
    rating: Number,
    ratingsData: [{type: Number}]

});

shopSchema.methods.rate = function(rating){
    this.ratingsData.push(rating);
    this.rating = _.mean(this.ratingsData);
    return this.ratingsData;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

The rate method is supposed to append a value passed to it to the ratingsData field and then return the average of that array. The problem I'm having is that everytime the method is called, `this.ratingsData` is just an empty array. The previous values aren't saved for some reason. Therefore the average I get is always the rating passed to the method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to insert data into database either do insert or  save to database. Before event trying to retrieve data & calculate mean values.   I dont see any save function.

Comment: You can perform operations after inserting value to the db.I cant understand  how you are trying achieve both things at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just didn't save the schema object, you need something like this:

```
shopSchema.methods.rate = function(rating, clb){
    this.ratingsData.push(rating);
    this.rating = _.mean(this.ratingsData);

    this.save(function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        return clb(result.ratingsData);
    })
};
```

or if you use Promise:

```
shopSchema.methods.rate = function(rating){
    this.ratingsData.push(rating);
    this.rating = _.mean(this.ratingsData);

    return this.save()
    .then(result=>{
        return result.ratingsData
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        throw err;
    })
};
```

Comment: This is what happens when I try to code at 4 am. I miss things like this. Thanks anyway.